# Не малая / немалая

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Теперь на моём сердце печаль, и не малая / немалая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Поддерживаю ответ Артема**, я бы тоже выбрала **раздельное** написание:

*Теперь на моём сердце печаль, **и не малая**.*

Вариант "немалая" возможен и **не является ошибкой**, так как существует прилагательное "немалый". Соответственно, постоянно приходится **делать выбор** между утверждением и отрицанием.

Но здесь следует обратить внимание на **обособленный** оборот с присоединительным значением "и не малая". При обособлении автор подчеркивает его **значимость**, а раздельное написание отрицательной частицы НЕ этому **соответствует**: печаль малой **не назовешь.**

**[Примеры из Нацкорпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8qGAoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QvdC1INC80LDQu9Cw0Y8wAQ==)**

**Виктор Астафьев.** Зрячий посох (1978-1982). Сейчас есть категория людей, **и не малая,** которым слова...

**Ю. М. Нагибин.** Дневник (1975) Вроде бы нет никаких оснований для этого, тем более, что война — **и не малая** — только что состоялась и кончилась поражением Америки, отнюдь не мечтающей о реванше.

**P.S. Мой голос** за Артема и за автора вопроса.

**НЕМАЛЫЙ**, 1. Довольно большой, **значительный по величине, размерам, количеству.** Росту он был немалого. Глубина здесь н-ая. Пройти н. путь. Н. вес. Заплатить н-ые деньги. Взять н-ые проценты. // Довольно продолжительный (о времени, сроке и т.п.). Двадцать лет - н. срок. 2. **Довольно значительный по силе, глубине и т.п.** Н. труд. Н-ые заботы, трудности. Доставить немалую радость. Н. успех. Н-ая заслуга. 3. Имеющий довольно большое значение; **значительный, важный.** Н. чин. Н-

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон! Я тоже вам плюсанул)

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ короткий, но очень ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ.  Я только подробно раскрыла его содержание, ничего нового не добавила)  Минимализм! Направление в искусстве и литературе)

Answer (score 3):

***Раздельно.*** *И* означает *причём,* а к нему напрашивается отрицание незначительности печали.